How to properly export/import to Unity?
First, am rotating so the height becomes the Y axis. Then, am converting it to fbx and saving it inside Unity with the transform set to 
As you can see, am leaving the forward as Z and the up as Y. This works fine and all, the scene is even exported with the scale (1, 1, 1) and the rotation (0, 0, 0), but its children have, for whatever reason, a localRotation.y of -180. Why? And how to set it to 0 without rotating it (for scripting purposes, I need everything consistent and I simply can't rotate the object becase that doesn't fix the issue).
Ultimately, I want a localScale of (1, 1, 1), a localRotation of (0, 0, 0) and a localPosition relative to the center of the scene per object (which already works, really only the -180 is the problem)
